# Formulating a formula for$ P_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

The sequence is $P_2=\dfrac 34, P_3=\dfrac 23, P_4=\dfrac 58, P_5=\dfrac 35, P_6=\dfrac 7{12}, P_7=\dfrac 47$. 
I'm having trouble putting this formula for $P_n$ on paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be the result of simplifying too much. Note that
$$P_2=\frac{3}{4},\quad P_3=\frac{4}{6},\quad P_4=\frac{5}{8},\quad P_5=\frac{6}{10}, \quad P_6=\frac{7}{12}, \quad P_7=\frac{8}{14}.$$

**Remark:** When we make calculations for small $n$ in order to get an idea of what might be going on, "simplifying too much" is a persistent issue. Even worse is the student habit of feeding expressions into a calculator: instead of a pattern, we get a jumble of digits.

Comment: Wow, yes that's it. Can't believe I didn't see it

Comment: I.e., $P_n = \frac{n + 1}{2 n}$. And I have the sneaky suspicion OP and @AndréNicolas share some background that we lack...

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{hint}$ : if $n$ is odd the numerator increases by $1$ and the denominator increases by $2$

if $n$ is even, the numerator increases by $2$, and the denominator by multiples of $4$.

Then combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, $$P_n=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

If $n$ is odd, $$P_n=\frac{n-k}{n}$$ where $P_n$ is the $k$th odd number in the sequence.